# Unable to get user.id from into django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm unable to get user.school.id into the form shown below.

I have not been able to know the reason as to why this is happening.
Below is my forms.py

```
class StudentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentsModel
        fields = ("school","adm","name","kcpe","form","stream","gender","notes")
        
        widgets = {
            'school':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control','value':'','id':'identifier','type':'hidden'}),
            "adm":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
            "name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
            "form":forms.Select(choices=class_forms,attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
            "stream":forms.Select(choices=streams,attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
            "gender":forms.Select(choices=gender, attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
        }
```

Below is the script from the template where the id is to reflect.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('identifier').value = '{{ user.school.id }}';
</script>
```

And this is the Students model

```
class StudentsModel(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adm = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    form = models.ForeignKey(FormModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(StreamModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(GenderModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s | %s" % (self.name,self.adm)
```

Please help me out. If there's anything else I need to add let me know.

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='default')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class User(AbstractUser):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True,default=1)
    #role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLES, blank=False, null=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.school) + ' | ' +  self.username)
```

The view

```
class AddStudentView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = StudentsModel
    form_class = StudentsForm
    template_name = 'students.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('students')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        streams = StreamModel.objects.filter(school=self.request.user.school)
        students = StudentsModel.objects.filter(school=self.request.user.school)
        forms = FormModel.objects.filter(school=self.request.user.school)
        context = super(AddStudentView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["streams"] = streams
        context["students"] = students
        context["forms"] = forms
        return context
```

The form is here

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    <span class="nav-item dropdown one " style="float:right">
        <a href="{% url 'export_students_details' %}" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Upload student details">Upload</a>
    </span>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why not encode the identifier in the URL of the view where you submit the data, usually that is how this is encoded.

Comment: Can you share the details of the `School` model and the view where you render this form?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, I added.

Comment: Cool. So what about get and post methods for the view?

Comment: How your template is expected to know what user is?

Comment: @alv2017. Through {% if user.is_authenticated %}

Comment: @Ptar, well it is not that easy :), before you will be able to do that, you need to say something like user=request.user: you are not getting user out of the blue, you get it out of request (or out of context). :)

Comment: I think you have an issue with business logic. The CreateView is used to create a new user, and effectively it means that the user is not registered on the system, and consequently he can not be logged in, so it is not surprising that you are unable to get user.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able t solve this by creating two different views, one for createview and the other for listview. This worked.